# Update 'username' one time rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wish a firestore's rule that check true only if the username is never changed...

*FirebaseAuth*: If the user is new, a function set a random username. Then the user changes this random username. Now I want a rule that set the username 'IMMUTABLE' (only one time)
So:
Can I try with a boolean flag in the document: 'isUsernameChanged'?

For each doc  I have a rule 'isOwner', and this is ok, but I want that he cannot change two time the username field, and only the username field for 2 times, the doc has other fields that he can always update.

I don't want (I would not) change the structure, maybe is better a new subcollection...?
or maybe also 'isUsernameChanged' has to go in a new (sub)collection?

grazie

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
function isUsernameCambiabile(){
    return (request.resource.data.username == resource.data.username || !getIfUsernameIsChanged() )
}
function getIfUsernameIsChanged(){
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/isUsernameChanged/$(request.auth.uid))
}
match /users/{idUser} {
...
allow update: if (isOwner(idUser) && isUsernameCambiabile()) 

match /isUsernameChanged/{idUser} {
  allow read: if isOwner(idUser) || isSuperAdmin();
  allow create: if isOwner(idUser) || isSuperAdmin();
  allow update: if false;
  allow delete: if false;
    }
}
```

when the user update his username the first time... a batch set a document with the same uid on isUsernameChanged sub-collection, a sub-collection like a flag!?

can I do better?
thx